# Matrix multiplicative inverse

Tags: aes, finite-field

How to determine the inverse multiplicative matrix of the following two irreducible polynomials GF(2^8)

x^8 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1 and x^8 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x +1

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. What did you search for this here and the www?

Comment: under which irreducible polynomial do you wish to invert those irreducible polynomials ?

Comment: @RichieFrame x^8  + x^4  + x^3+x+1